# wrong order when use scale_color_manual in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the color of my line chart using scale_color_manual function in ggplot2.
Here is the description of my data:

```
week10 acc10 week11 acc11 week12 acc12 week13 acc13 week14 acc14 week15 acc15 week16 acc16
1      1  7696      1  7535      1  6916      1  6511      1  6843      1  6638      1  6759
2      2  9389      2  8978      2  8332      2  8016      2  7842      2  7939      2  7954
3      3 10204      3  9599      3  8873      3  8682      3  8638      3  8494      3  8506
4      4 10136      4  9775      4  8946      4  8340      4  8935      4  8526      4  8739
5      5  9860      5  9667      5  9075      5  8717      5  8807      5  8706      5  8868
6      6 11546      6 11080      6 10402      6  9473      6  9836      6  9715      6  9570
7      7  9372      7  9308      7  8646      7  7834      7  8124      7  7848      7  8050
```

Below is my code:

```
ggplot()+   
  geom_line(data = new.dat,
            aes(y = acc10, x = week11, colour = "#75D701"), size=1.3) +
  geom_line(data = new.dat, aes(y = acc11, x = week11, colour = "#88dba3"), size=1.3) + 
  geom_line(data = new.dat, aes(y = acc12, x = week12, colour = "#3ac569"), size=1.3) +  
  geom_line(data = new.dat, aes(y = acc13, x = week13, colour = "#f9a11b"), size=1.3) +   
  geom_line(data = new.dat, aes(y = acc14, x = week14, colour = "#0080ff"), size=1.3) +
  geom_line(data = new.dat, aes(y = acc15, x = week15, colour = "#f9d423"), size=1.3) +
  geom_line(data = new.dat, aes(y = acc16, x = week16, colour = "#00dffc"), size=1.3) + 
  xlab("Day") +
  ylab("the Number of Accidents") +
  labs(title = "Total Number of Accidents during Weekdays in Different Year")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#75D701", "#88dba3", "#3ac569", "#f9a11b", 
                                "#0080ff", "#f9d423", "#00dffc"))
```

Here is the picture I got:

[image]

I want the color of the topmost line to be in green. The hex code for it is "#75D701". "https://www.color-hex.com/color/75d701

However, it turns out to be orange in my result. I spent several hours on this problem, but I failed to fix it.

Any suggestion will be great help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to `reshape` your data first. Calling several `geom_line` is inefficient. It's better to provide sample data using `dput(head(mydata,20))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
 library(tidyverse)
    as.tibble(df) %>% 

      select(contains("week"),everything()) %>% 
      gather("id","value",8:ncol(.)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(week16,value,col=id))+geom_line()+
     scale_color_manual(values=c("#75D701","#88dba3","#3ac569","#f9a11b","#0080ff","#f9d423","#00dffc"))
```

You can modify the example as you wish.
This gives you this.
[image]

Comment: That's awesome!!! It is exactly what I am trying to draw. Thank you so much for your suggestion!!

Comment: Please feel free to accept this answer if it helped.